# Kotlin: Extension inside class

Tags: kotlin

I have an extension function inside class

```
class Utils{
    private var x : Int = 0;

    public fun Utils.multiply() : Int{
        return this.x*100;
    }
}
```

Why I can use extension multiply inside another

```
fun Utils.add() : Int{
    return this.multiply()+100
}
```

But can not use in class Main

```
class Main{
    val utils = Utils()


    val multi = utils.multiply() //error : Unresolved reference
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating an extebsion function inside the class instead of a regular method?

Comment: I am learning kotlin. this is a theoretical question

Comment: I think that class-scope extension functions are excellent, but I would argue most (if not *all*) of them should be `private`. That would additionally solve the arguable inconsistencies

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you declare an extension function inside a class, it's only accessible inside the class's scope. There's just no way to refer to it directly (at the moment anyway).

You can use a scope function to put yourself in that scope though:

```
val multi = utils.run { multiply() }
```

But you can only access *public* functions this way - if the extension function is *private* inside that class, you have to actually be running the code inside that class where the function is visible. Doing `classWithPrivateStuff.run { superPrivateFunction() }` won't get around those restrictions

Comment: @dr_yand An example from kotlin docs. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members

Comment: Note also that you get a confusing scenario where you can run `utils.run { otherUtils.multiply() }`.